# Operação SUM duplicando valor na query - Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

estou com uma query que está com algum problema na qual não consigo identificar.

Preciso trazer o somatório de adicional e de jornada. O problema é que quando adiciono no banco o valor da jornada e nenhum valor para o adicional ele vem certo. A partir do momento que adiciono mais de 1 registro no adicional ele duplica o valor registrado em jornada.

Ex:
[image: Parte do Adicional]

[image: Parte da Jornada]

No banco de dados está assim:

[image: Adicional]
[image: Jornada]

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_falta','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_ferias','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.id_servidor')
->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor',DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno.nr_adicional),0) as adicional'),
    DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.nr_extensao),0) as jornada'),
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*',DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor) as faltas'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor) as ferias'))
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria',$request->cd_secretaria)
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia',$request->id_referencia)
->groupBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_lancado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_aprovado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.ds_observacao',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_grat_reuniao')
->orderby('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
->skip($partes)
->take(300)
->get();
```

O retorno que essa query gera é esse:

[image: Retorno]

Era para trazer o valor de 10 em jornada. Mas está trazendo 20.

Creio que o que está com problema seja nessa parte:

```
DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno.nr_adicional),0) as adicional'),
DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.nr_extensao),0) as jornada'),
```

PS: Estou usando Postgresql.

SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor,
    COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno.nr_adicional),
            0) AS adicional,
    COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.nr_extensao),
            0) AS jornada,
    sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*,
    COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor) AS faltas,
    COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor) AS ferias
FROM
    sch_sismapa.tb_servidor
        INNER JOIN
    sch_decom.tb_servidor ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula = sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula
        LEFT JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id = sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade.id_servidor
        LEFT JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_falta ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id = sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor
        LEFT JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_ferias ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id = sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor
        LEFT JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id = sch_sismapa.tb_adicional_noturno.id_servidor
        LEFT JOIN
    sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch ON sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id = sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.id_servidor
WHERE
    sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria = '7'
        AND sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia = '9'
GROUP BY sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_lancado , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_aprovado , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.ds_observacao , sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_grat_reuniao
ORDER BY sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento ASC , sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor ASC
LIMIT 300 OFFSET 0
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você rodar a query diretamente no banco de dados retorna corretamente o valor ?

Comment: Sim. Ele retorna o valor 10.

Comment: então faz isso, atualiza a pergunta com uma query de exemplo, e tampem faz isso aqui: `var_dump($servidores);` porem troque o `->get()`por `->toSql();`

Comment: Cara ele retorna o valor 20, em vez de 10. Falei errado para você. Vou colocar o SQL no texto para vc ver.

Comment: Então, tanto o eloquent quanto no sql direto ele retornar o valor errado?

Comment: Sim. Os dois estão retornando valores errados @Bulfaitelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

Na verdade tive que repensar na estratégia. Em vez de fazer uma única query eu fiz várias querys pois o erro estava no leftjoin onde eu utilizava o

> COALESCE(SUM())

Portanto, separei as querys e depois adicionei o resultado dela no meu objeto principal.

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_periculosidade','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_periculosidade.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_ferias','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_ferias_premio','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_ferias_premio.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_falta','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_vacancia','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_vacancia.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_sem_vencimento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_sem_vencimento.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_medica','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_medica.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_acidente_trabalho','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_acidente_trabalho.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_a','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_a.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_b','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_b.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_c','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_c.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_d','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_d.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_a','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_a.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_b','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_b.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_c','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_c.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_d','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_d.id_servidor')
->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*','sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade.ds_insalubridade',
        'sch_sismapa.tb_periculosidade.ds_periculosidade',DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor) as ferias'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias_premio.id_servidor) as fereiasp'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor) as faltas'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_vacancia.id_servidor) as vacancias'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_sem_vencimento.id_servidor) as lsv'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_licenca_medica.id_servidor) as lm'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_acidente_trabalho.id_servidor) as acitrab'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_a.id_servidor) as pna'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_b.id_servidor) as pnb'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_c.id_servidor) as pnc'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_norm_d.id_servidor) as pnd'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_a.id_servidor) as pca'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_b.id_servidor) as pcb'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_c.id_servidor) as pcc'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_penosidade_chefia_d.id_servidor) as pcd'))
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria',$request->cd_secretaria)
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia',$request->id_referencia)
->groupBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula',
        'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias',
        'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_lancado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_aprovado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.ds_observacao',
        'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_grat_reuniao','sch_sismapa.tb_insalubridade.ds_insalubridade','sch_sismapa.tb_periculosidade.ds_periculosidade')
->orderby('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
->skip($partes)
->take(300)
->get();

$jornadas = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
                    ->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
                    ->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.id_servidor')
                    ->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(sch_sismapa.tb_extensao_ch.nr_extensao),0) as jornada'))
                    ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria',$request->cd_secretaria)
                    ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia',$request->id_referencia)
                    ->groupBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias')
                    ->orderby('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
                    ->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
                    ->skip($partes)
                    ->take(300)
                    ->get();

foreach ($servidores as $value => $servidor) {

$servidor->jornada = $jornadas[$value]->jornada;
}
```